# Using Firebase Authentication inside C# WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to using Firebase Authentication for authenticating my user through an
Email confirmation, but as i read from the Docs [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/where-to-start) there are no C# documentation in there. I only able to find Firestore Database from the Documentation, is there any guide or official/unofficial documentation?

Answer (score 2):

The tutorials in the documentation can be applied for any language of choice as longs as there is support for that language in Firebase, which is the case for C#. So I would recommend you to while checking the documentation you shared, also take a look at the [Firebase .NET SDK library documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet), more specifically everything under `FirebaseAdmin.Auth`.

That being said, if you'd like to have a step by step guide, I found this [Firebase Auth tutorial for C# in Medium](https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-c-library-8e5e1c30acc2), which might be exactly what you are looking for.

As per the comments to this question, this is likely due to the fact that Firebase is not that popular within C# uses, but if you'd like to have this official documentation added you can always open a request in [Firebase Bug Report](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) and state why this is needed so that Firebase's team can add it.

Comment: thanks for answering, but can i get the complete docs like [Android Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth)? Because i was confused with many tutorials outhere who used old method like **Firesharp** and any open source Library.

Comment: Well, here is the thing, the Firebase team did not provide a step by step guide for C#, so like I said in the answer, you might need to apply the concepts of other tutorials, like the android one, while using the C# libraries.

Comment: Well i see. that's pretty sad if they don't provide a complete Docs like Android do, to think C# is one of the popular languages.

Comment: I agree, maybe this is because it's not so popular with Firebase, but then again, if you'd like to have this official documentation added you can always open a request in [Firebase Bug Report](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) and state why this is needed so that Firebase's team can add it. I will add this to the answer so it's more complete, please consider accepting it if you believed it helped.